# Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 56

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi. I have a little problem. When I have selected the file. The selected file cannot be uploaded and an error console will appear Error: FormatException: SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON. This error occurred after I upgraded the flutter version. Can anyone help me?

Code:

```
_uploadDocument(String fileTitle) async {
    print("Upload Document..");
    var fileName = selectedDocument.name;
    var uri = Uri.parse(widget.apiEndPoint);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.fields['Resize'] = 'false';
    request.fields['MultipartFile'] = 'true';
    request.fields['API'] = 'UploadImage';
    request.fields['Token'] = widget.token;

    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
        'File', _selectedDocument,
        contentType: new MediaType('image', 'png'), filename: fileName));

    var streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _progressBarActive = false;
      });
      var result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
      if (result['ResponseCode'] == "0") {
        if (result['Data'] != null) {
          print(result['Data']['banner']);
          PatientDocument prepare = PatientDocument(
              result['Data']['banner'],
              fileTitle,
              'Telemedicine Patient Evaluation document.',
              dateEpocMilisecond.toString(),
              selectedDocument.name);
          setState(() {
            _patientDocument.add(prepare);
          });
        }
      } else if (result['ResponseCode'] != "0") {
        _alertDialog(context, result['ResponseMsg']);
        if (result['ResponseCode'] == "1") {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              '/signin', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is `response.body`?